# The view getdata.views.getview didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to make a form in django. First it was not creating object of the form then it was not saving the data and now I'm getting "The view getdata.views.getview didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." error. 
This is my views.py file

```
def getview(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form1 = ro_input_form(
        request.POST)  # Please use CamelCase when writing Class Name(according to pep8 style guide
    if form1.is_valid():
        form1.origin = form1.cleaned_data['origin']
        form1.destination = form1.cleaned_data['destination']
        form1.timeWindow = form1.cleaned_data['time_window']
        print(form1.origin, form1.destination, form1.time_window)

        form1.save()
else:  # Handling GET request here
    form1 = ro_input_form()
return render(request, 'inputform.html', {'form1': form1})
```

This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import form_input
class ro_input_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = form_input
        fields = ('origin', 'destination', 'timeWindow')
```

This is my html file :

```
                                            <form method="Post">
                                                {% csrf_token %}
                                                {{form1}}
                                                <input type="submit" class="forform" value="sumbit values">

                                            </form>
```

Comment: your code has a few repetitive lines `request.method == "POST"` is written twice and `form1 = ro_input_form(request.POST)` is written twice, just call it once, anyway     back to your question, can you see those print statements output on your console?

Comment: Can you correct the indentation of your view code?

Comment: @SammyJ  I've edited the views.py but its not following any post request in this.

Comment: @JPG I've edited the views.py but its not following any post request in this.

Answer (score 1):

If your indentation is correct, then you need to update your view to handle `GET` request:

```
def getview(request):
    form1 = ro_input_form(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form1.is_valid():
            form1.save()
    return render(request, 'inputform.html', {'form1': form1})
```

Comment: I've edited the views.py with correct indentation. But its still not processing the post request. Data is not going in database. I'm new to django.

Comment: @ChiragGulati can you please try with the updated code please(please don't modify the code)? If you face any error, please add it to the question. also please add the form code as well if this code with answer does not work. thanks

Comment: @c.grey I've edited my question with my forms.py in it.

Comment: @ChiragGulati is the code given with the answer working? :) If not, what error are you facing?

Comment: @ruddra yes, code is running but its still not savings any data in database.